# linux compare two variable

Tags: bash

The script found error but it always goes to Else condition "No Found Error".  Am I missing how to compare two variables?

```
ERROR="Error:"
for i in `find /logs -mtime -1`
do
CHECK=`cat $i |grep -i "Error"|cut -f 1 -d " "`
if [ "$CHECK" == $ERROR ]
then
  echo "Found Error"
else
 echo "Not Found Error"
fi
done
```

Comment: `[ "$CHECK" = "$ERROR" ]` would be most correct, but the issue here seems to be that `CHECK` doesn't have the value you think it does. Be sure to run this through http://shellcheck.net and fix the errors it points out.

Comment: Why not just `if grep -qi $i "^Error:"`? No need for useless `cat` or `cut`, nor for `ERROR` or `CHECK` variables.

Comment: Are you sure the word Error will be in the first field?

Comment: And note: why do you think the OS needs to be in the title?

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried something like `if [[ "$CHECK" == $ERROR ]]` ?

To simply detect error without printing the error message, you can use

```sh
CHECK=$(cat $i | grep "Error" | wc -l)
if [[ $CHECK -ne 0 ]]
then
   echo "Found error"
else
   echo "Not found error"
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

There is two things that I would advise and may fix your issue:

1. Add `#!/bin/bash` on the first line, to make sure it is interpreted as bash and not sh. Many time I had trouble with comparison because of this
2. When comparing two variables, uses double brackets (`[[` and `]]`)  Also, if it strings, always put quotes `"$ERROR"` around it. It's missing for the `$ERROR` variable.

Look at the other answers also, there are many ways to do the same thing in a much simpler way.

*Note: When comparing numbers you should use `-eq`*

Comment: Numbers *aren't* being compared here; there's no point bringing up `-eq`.

Comment: Yes, I corrected it.

Comment: These are just two pieces of advice, not answers to the question.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `grep -i` for case-insensitive matching, but then testing the result for exact equality with the string `Error:`.  If the case-insensitive matching is important then the exact equality test is not an appropriate complement.

You are also capturing a potentially multi-line output and comparing it to a string that can be the result only of a single-line output.

And you are matching "Error:" anywhere on the line, but assuming that it will appear at the beginning.

Overall, you are going about this a very convoluted way, as `grep` tells you via its exit status whether it found any matches.  For example:

```
#!/bin/bash

for log in `find /logs -mtime -1`; do
  if grep -i -q '^Error:' "$log"; then
    echo "Found Error"
  else
    echo "Not Found Error"
  fi
done
```